# Oracle SQL Query for a complicated requirement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following oracle database table USERS

[image]

I have to display the user status begin date&time and end date&time for each status.

From the above example I need to display like STEVE BALE is LOGGED_OUT from 01/08/2013 12:00:00 AM to 01/08/2013 5:04:24.736437 AM

and UNAVAILABLE from 01/08/2013 5:04:24.736437 AM to 01/08/2013 6:04:24.736437 AM,

and AVAILABLE from 01/08/2013 6:04:24.736437 AM to 01/08/2013 7:31:08.591801 AM...

similarly for the given day last record new status, useR STEVE BALE is LOGGED_OUT from 01/08/2013 11:30:50.724405 AM to 01/08/2013 11:59:59 PM..

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy, because oracle has the `lead()` function.  Something like:

```
select t.*,
       lead(status_change_date) over (partition by user_name order by status_change_date) as end_status_time
from t
```

For a string, you can do something like:

```
select (t.user_name||' is '||t.new_status||' from '||
        to_char(status_change_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi')+' to '||
        to_char(lead(status_change_date) over (partition by user_name order by status_change_date),
                'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi')
       ) as thestring
from t
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. For the first record I need to return something ike STEVE BALE is LOGGED_OUT from 01/08/2013 12:00:00 AM to 01/08/2013 5:04:24.736437 AM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example if I understood your correctly. Use your date/time column in "to" part:

```
Select 'STEVE BALE is LOGGED_OUT from: '||to_char(trunc(Sysdate), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')||' to '||to_char((trunc(sysdate)+5/24)+04/1440, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') "in_out"
From dual;

SQL> STEVE BALE is LOGGED_OUT from: 01/09/2013 12:00:00 AM to 01/09/2013 05:04:00 AM
```

To get values from prev./next row use Lag/Lead as suggested by Gordon.